# ALM-PC - Error "Change Machine Identity Failed" occurred while trying to add PC Host VM

Tags: loadrunner, alm, hp-performance-center

I am using HPE-PC 12.55 version. While trying to add new PC host machine (already did host configurations), getting an error Change Machine Identity Failed.

Tried below resolutions in order to resolve issue but no luck -

1. Restarted all ALM machines
2. Restarted IIS on PC servers and also restarted ALM service(s).
3. Added IUSR_METRO user as local administrators on host machine.
4. Restarted PC services of host machine [Performance Center Agent and Performance Center Load Testing Service]

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjIjN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the host machine? (not only services)
There are cases that after installation that don't require reboot Windows prevents user configuration unless a reboot is performed.

Comment: Yes. I did restart host machine after installation as a standard procedure. But not helped fixing issue.

Comment: Why did you had to add IUSR_METRO  to the local administrators group manually? It should by done as part of the host installation. Please check that IUSR_METRO is still part of the administrators group as there might be an IT script that automatically removes local users from the administrators group.

Comment: Yes, there is IT security script that removes IUSR_METRO from machine after 3-4 hours of addition as an local administrators. But I ensured that IUSR_METRO is administrator before trying to add machine as PC Host.